# Recorrer un array multinivel con php

Tags: php

Tengo un inconveniente a la hora de recorrer un array multinivel con `foreach` usando PHP. La finalidad de esto es hacer un menu de categorias y subcategorias pero de momento no he tenido exito al acceder a los valores.
Aquí es donde obtengo los datos:

```html
foreach($data as $d){     
  $grupos[$d['nombre_categoria']][$d['id_categoria']][] = array(                                                                                                                                                                      
      'sub_cat' => array(
         'id_sub_cat' => $d['id_sub_categoria'],
         'nombre_sub' => $d['nombre_sub_categoria']  
       )                 
   );   
  }
```

Mi array resultante es el siguiente:

```html
[
  'Artesanias' => [
    6 => [
      0 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '1',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Accesorios',
        ],
      ],
      1 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '2',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Bolsos',
        ],
      ],
      2 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '5',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Hamacas',
        ],
      ],
      3 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '4',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Mantas guajiras',
        ],
      ],
      4 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '8',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Manteles',
        ],
      ],
      5 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '3',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Mochilas',
        ],
      ],
      6 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '9',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Muñecas tejidas',
        ],
      ],
      7 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '11',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Navidad',
        ],
      ],
      8 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '10',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Ropa tejida',
        ],
      ],
      9 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '7',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Sillas',
        ],
      ],
      10 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '6',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Tambores',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
  'Folclor y gaitas' => [
    1 => [
      0 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '12',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Gaitas hembras',
        ],
      ],
      1 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '13',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Gaitas macho',
        ],
      ],
      2 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '16',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Llamador',
        ],
      ],
      3 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '18',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Maracas',
        ],
      ],
      4 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '17',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Pito atravesao',
        ],
      ],
      5 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '14',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Sombreros',
        ],
      ],
      6 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '15',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Tambora',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
  'Hogar y decoracion' => [
    5 => [
      0 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '28',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Armarios',
        ],
      ],
      1 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '27',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Camas',
        ],
      ],
      2 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '26',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Muebles',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
  'Obras de arte' => [
    2 => [
      0 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '19',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Pinturas',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
  'Papeleria y cacharreria' => [
    3 => [
      0 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '21',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Archivadores',
        ],
      ],
      1 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '22',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Cartulina',
        ],
      ],
      2 => [
        'sub_cat' => [
          'id_sub_cat' => '20',
          'nombre_sub' => 'Resmas',
        ],
      ],
    ],
  ],
]
```

He tratado de recorrer el contenido de `$grupos` utilizando `foreach` anidados y accediendo a los valores pero no logro acceder a ninguno de los valores ¿Qué me podrían recomendar?

Comment: Por favor agrega el código que has intentado, no importa que no funcione, es la única forma en la que podemos ayudarte a encontrar el error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema que tienes es que el array que generas es de 3 dimensiones y no de 2 como piensas.

para recorrerlo haz lo siguiente:

```html
foreach($grupos as $g => $elementos){
    //imprimimos el nombre de la categoria principal
    echo $g;
    //extraemos la primera llave, ya que solo tiene una
    $key = (int)array_key_first($elementos);
    
        foreach ($elementos[$key] as $k => $e) {
            //imprimimos el nombre de la sub categoria
            echo "-" . $e["nombre_sub"];
        }

}
```